# Dynamodb, nosql or go back to RDBMS

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, rdbms

*This is my table*

```
  0: {A : 12, B: "can you help me", C:[56, 44]}
  1: {A : 32, B: "where are you", C:[23, 55]}
  2: {A : 14, B: "please help", C:[14, 12]}
```

i want to query my table with a VALUE which is either in C or equal to A.

For ex, according to the table above, i want all the rows **where A == 12 OR 12 in C**,

*the result would be :*

```
0: {A : 12, B: "can you help me", C:[56, 44]}
2: {A : 14, B: "please help", C:[14, 12]}
```

- can't use GSI on a set, [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)
- with filter expression I can't paginate,

**My questions are :**

- Is this use case impossible to resolve using dynamodb
- was dynamodb the right choice, and would it be better on RDBMS

Comment: what do you mean by where `VALUE in C or equal to A`?

Comment: i mean i query my table with a value, this one is either in C or equal to A, i edited my question @bestwishes

Comment: dynamodb is more inclined towards key value put/get, you can use elastic search with dynamodb to solve this use case, but this will cost you.

Comment: assuming that A/C are serving as secondary key not as primary key, one Solution which I won't recommends is, denormalize/duplicate the data with contents of A and C. i.e. for {A : 12, B: "can you help me", C:[56, 44]} make 3 records
{A : 12, B: "can you help me", C:[56, 44], SK :12},
{A : 12, B: "can you help me", C:[56, 44], SK :56},
{A : 12, B: "can you help me", C:[56, 44], SK :44}
now you can query based on sort key, but you will have to take special care while doing an update since there might be stale entries after update.